# Get employees list whose age is above 65 years old and get the records before 3 months or 6 months

Tags: mysql

I have a condition where I have to get the employee's retirement list. i.e whose age is greater or equal to 65. and I have an option , to show the results before 3 or 6 months of the employee retirement date, I have prepared a query , where I am getting above 65 years, but not getting results before 3 or 6 months. Any suggestions will be very helpful. Thank you.
Below is my query

```sql
SELECT e.emp_id,
       e.first_name,
       e.date_of_birth
FROM employee AS e
JOIN employee_job_info AS eji
    ON e.id=eji.employee_id
WHERE timestampdiff(year, e.date_of_birth,curdate()) >= 65
        OR floor(datediff(DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH), e.date_of_birth) / 365) >= 65
```

Comment: *I have an option , to show the results before 3 or 6 months of the employee retirement date* Unclear condition... demonstrate it on some sample data.

Comment: If an employee date of retirement is on 2022-01-01 then his result should display, as I want to show those results before 3 months of his retirement date i.e before 2022-01-01

Comment: If so then simply add needed months amount to CURRENT_DATE in `TIMESTAMPDIFF`. I.e. query the output like it will look like after needed amount of months, not today. And remove 2nd condition at all.

Comment: Please share more details, like the table structure, sample input data, the expected output corresponding to that input data, and your attempts to resolve the problem. What **exactly** is not working with the query you have shared?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would say create two views:

- retired_employees
- goingToBeRetired_employees

For the first view your query would be something like:

```
create view retired_employees 
as SELECT e.emp_id,e.first_name, e.date_of_birth 
from 
employee as e JOIN employee_job_info as eji on e.id=eji.employee_id 
where timestampdiff(year, e.date_of_birth,curdate())>=65
```

second view:

```
create view goingToBeRetired_employees 
as SELECT e.emp_id,e.first_name, e.date_of_birth 
from 
employee as e JOIN employee_job_info as eji on e.id=eji.employee_id 
where timestampdiff(month, e.date_of_birth,curdate()) between 64*12+6 and 64*12+9
```